# HP laptop intermittently enters tablet mode and forgets about keyboard and trackpad

Tags: windows, windows-11, hardware-failure, touchscreen, tablet-mode

My HP Pavilion x360 laptop running Windows 11 will sometimes enter tablet mode on its own. In this mode, it does not recognise the internal keyboard and trackpad and only accepts touchscreen input.

Is there any way to fix this? This only happens when waking up the computer from sleep or booting it up, never during usage. So this makes me believe it is a software issue rather a loose hardware connection.

Comment: Update UEFI before anything else. If the problem persists contact tech support.

Comment: What do you do in order to get it working again after boot or sleep?

Comment: I have a wireless keyboard and mouse set that I can use when it doesn't detect the internal devices. Otherwise, I use the touchscreen to restart the computer and hope it detects it.

Answer (score 0):

If the bios update fails, just disable the touchscreen driver in device manager, and turn off tablet mode within settings.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to turn off Tablet mode in Windows 11. I will turn off the touchscreen driver and see if that fixes things.